# DataTables column data convert properly

Tags: javascript, datatable

this is what i look at
[image]

and this is what i received from server
[image]

```
  function requestData() {
    $.ajax({        
        url: "<c:url value='/abs/guide/guideSampleChartData1Ajax.do'/>",    
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            for(var i in data) {
                chart.addSeries({
                    name: data[i].name,
                    data: data[i].data
                });         
            }

            console.log(data);

            $("#table").dataTable({
                "data": data,
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "name" },
                    { "data": "categData" },                        
                    { "data": "data"}
                ]   
            });
        }
    });
}
```

and this is my code, i want to my datatables looking accordingly
so, what part of code, i change??

Comment: Both response looks same know?

Comment: i changed the image ..